# Python segfaults when subprocess is sent SIGTERM

Tags: python, qt, segmentation-fault, subprocess, pyside

I spawn a subprocess in python as follows:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(
  [process, arg1, arg2],
  env= current_env, cwd=exec_path, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

My problem occurs when I send the subprocess a SIGTERM (from the shell, not python).

If I use `proc.read()` to read the results of `proc`'s stdout, then I end up deadlocked (as expected due to use of PIPE) but python does not crash.

However, if I use `proc.communicate()` then python segfaults. As I understand it, no matter what the child does, this should not impact the parent process (python) in any way!

What I would like to do is to call `proc.communicate()`, and then check `proc.returncode` which should indicate any problems with the child process.

I am using Python 2.7.3

Thanks!

**EDIT:**
Another thing to note is that this is run in a QThread (PySide.QtCore.QThread).

**EDIT2:**

Minimal example:

The example runs correctly outside a QThread context, thus the problem seems to be related to it.

*process.py:*

```
class A(QThread):
  def run(self):
    pp = subprocess.Popen(["./loop.sh"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    output = pp.communicate()
    print('Now send SIGTERM to loop.sh and watch me crash')
```

*loop.sh*

```
#!/bin/bash
while true; do : ; done
```

Comment: Can you add a toy example that segfaults ?

Comment: I use the `SIGTERM`/`communicate()`/`returncode` pattern successfully without PySide, leading me to suspect that you may have some strange interaction between PySide and `subprocess` going on here.

Comment: @Scharron I have added an example.

Comment: @zigg that may well be the case, I shall try the same example outside the QThread context.

Comment: @zigg It does indeed run without problems outside a QThread!